# 3 vectors function multipole expansion

Tags: calculus, mathematical-physics, spherical-harmonics, coupling

Normally a function depends on 2 vectors can be expanded in term of spherical harmonics as 
$v(|\vec{r_1}-\vec{r_2}|)=\sum_L v_L(r_1,r_2) \sum_M Y^M_L(\vec{r_1})Y^{M*}_L(\vec{r_2})$. 
So for a function depends on 3 vectors such as $v(|\vec{R}+\vec{r_2}-\vec{r_1}|)$, how can I expand it in terms of spherical harmonics ?